# how can we use chrome browser with capybara+ selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am using gems
    capybara (2.0.2)
    cucumber (1.2.1)
    selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)

and in my env.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

Its open blank new chrome tab in existing chrome window then my test cases is giving error.

```
end of file reached (EOFError)
```

but my test cases is working fine with firefox.

Comment: Show a full backtrace, please

Comment: I think you need to change that last line: Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [support file gist](https://gist.github.com/rosskevin/5937888) that will get you all you need and more for your javascript/selenium/webkit/headless setup.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name 'selenium'
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:firefox_profile => profile)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, { :browser => :remote, :desired_capabilities => capabilities })
end
```